# javascript: how to sort out when divs are changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort the list of users, where users do frequently change
(#userList>div)

```
sortUsersAZ = function() {
  var $divs = $('#userList>div');
  var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).data('username') > $(b).data('username');
  });
  $('#userList').html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
};
```

It works randomly. Seems that when #userList>div changes, the sort function stops

Any idea ?

Comment: What you mean `#userList>div changes`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to refactor your 'sort' function. I think it has to be something similar to this:

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = $(a).data('username').toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = $(b).data('username').toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase

  if (nameA < nameB) { return -1; }
  if (nameA > nameB) { return 1; }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
})
```

Feel free to check the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: This looks correct to me. The user-defined `sort` function has to return -1, 0 or +1, not true/false.